# MapKit Annotations based on Date

Tags: ios, date, annotations, mapkit

I have a map that displays an array of annotations. These annotations are all called from a plist and each have a date at which they occur. I would like these annotations to display only on the date that they happen, however I have no clue how to approach this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think about an observer on NSDate but thats just a guess. However, you can make local notification and when you receive the notification add the annotation?

Answer (score 0):

Access the string for key using fast enumeration.  Here is an example of how to accomplish this if you are using standardDefaults for your plist:

```
for (NSString *dateString in yourArray) {
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"__enterDateKeyHere__"];
}
```

Comment: It gives me an error stating "Expects '.' in 'for' statement specifier. Do you know how to fix this?